# Failed Authentication. Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, bitnami-kafka

I have converted Bitnami Kafka helm chart to kubernetes yaml file.
I'm deploying it on AWS EKS. But when running this command

```
kubectl --namespace test-microservices exec -it pod/kafka-controller-0 -- kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list kafka:9092 --topic mytopic --producer.config /opt/bitnami/kafka/config/producer.properties
```

Its gives me this error

```
INFO [SocketServer listenerType=BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /10.1.26.148 (channelId=10.1.26.250:9092-10.1.26.148:24905-2) (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

What should I do about it? I will mention the files that have been created when converting helm to Kubernetes file and also the sequence in which I have deployed the files.
Files created are:
[tree-structure-of-files-created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddpyh.png)

First I have applied yaml files from rbac folder and then persistent-volume folder and then from the main folder i.e scripts-configmap.yaml, secrets.yaml and svc.yml file. Finally deploying files from controller-eligible.